# Should a component's render method have return type React.ReactNode or JSX.Element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Both seem to result in no compilation errors, but what's the difference and is one preferable to the other?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This exact question was asked over in the [react-typescript-cheatsheet repo issue #57](https://github.com/sw-yx/react-typescript-cheatsheet/issues/57)

To [quote the original answer](https://github.com/sw-yx/react-typescript-cheatsheet/issues/57#issuecomment-451582715.):

> Regardless of what a component ends up rendering, `React.createElement` always returns an object, which is the `JSX.Element` interface, but `React.ReactNode` is the set of all possible return values of a component.
>
> - `JSX.Element` -> Return value of `React.createElement`
> - `React.ReactNode` -> Return value of a component

Generally, I think the idea is that `JSX.Element` specifically describes the interface of `React.createElement` and is narrow in scope whereas `React.ReactNode` is more broad and covers all possible values that a Component could return.

Comment: But for a components `render()` method, should it be `render(): React.ReactNode` or `render(): JSX.Element`? I am not sure what the practical consequences of each are.

Comment: I think there are cases where a React Component might not return a JSX. You could return another function or you could return a `string` and in those cases I think `JSX.Element` might not work.

Answer (score 9):

It depends. ReactJS in principle *can* [render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render):

```
type RenderType = JSX.Element* | Array<RenderType> | string | number | boolean | null
// * includes Portal, Fragment
// for both function and class components
// (type doesn't exist in React type declarations)
```

TS render types are currently [*limited* to](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699):

- [Class component](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/67fdf14/types/react/index.d.ts#L502): `ReactNode` (wider than permitted by React)
- [Function component](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/67fdf14/types/react/index.d.ts#L555): `JSX.Element | null` (more restrictive than React)

`JSX.Element` is more or less the same as `ReactElement`, you can use both interchangeably.