# What would be the return type for React function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new typescript and React.

I was creating a container

```
import React from 'react'

interface containerProps {
  heading: string,
  para: string
}

const container = (props: containerProps) => {
    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

but this is giving me an error in JSX saying `type expected.`

What should be react JSX return type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544483/should-a-components-render-method-have-return-type-react-reactnode-or-jsx-eleme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using React 16.8, the right way of providing typings would be to use `React.FC` or `React.FunctionComponent`. Then, we can provide the component's props(`ContainerProps`) as part of the generics parameter.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ContainerProps {
  heading: string,
  para: string
}

const container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = (props: ContainerProps) => {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```